# the .click event not working ONLY for the last button (events defined in a for-loop)

Tags: for-loop, jquery-click-event

I made a function that sets .click for the number of buttons passed to it.

The function is called when another Jquery detects the number of buttons on the page

```
...
var n = $(".button").length + 1;
...
set_navig(n);
...

function set_navig(n){
    for(i=1 ; i<n ; i++){
        var btn = "#pb" + i;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(btn).click(function(){
                alert('Working!');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I have tried removing or adding buttons on the page - correct (n) is passed to the function, but ALWAYS only the last one doesn't work at all.

ANY IDEAS?

---

Thnx to EVERYBODY for so much good stuff available here. You where the major source of Jquery knowledge when I started learning it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I originally thought you should use i<=n, but you pass length + 1 (that's unusual by the way). You could just pass the button array instead of the length. Then you can iterate through each one.

I don't see a specific error with the code other than style, so perhaps you are not getting as many .button objects as you think or perhaps you have a typo in the last ID. You should paste a sample of the html code or just debug it yourself using alert() to see what values are being passed.

For future reference, common loops in many languages are either: `for(i=0;i<n;i++){}` or `for(i=1;i<=n;i++){}` I would say passing length + 1 to your function is very poor practice.